# Where does tesla radiant energy come from?

Tags: electricity

Few days ago, I had read an article about tesla radiant energy.I want to know whether this energy comes from the air or the wasted energy in radio stations?

Comment: Do you have a reference?

Answer (score 6):

Tesla Radiant Energy comes from the minds of people who want there to be something beyond Maxwell's equations, laws of thermodynamics and conservation of energy, all that boring stuff that stops wonderful things that they want to happen, happening. See also tin-foil-hat, and perpetual motion.

A Tesla coil emits ordinary electromagnetic radiation, but very inefficiently as it is not designed to be an antenna, so does not match the impedance of free space well at all.

It can also emit very pretty sparks!

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand the "tesla radiant energy" is a fake concept.

It is possible to use energy transmitted by radio waves to power some devices, crystal radio is a good example.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crystal_radio

Same holds true for other transmitted signals that can be used to induce currents and voltages in circuitry, typically using antennas or coils.

Note that "Tesla coil" is not a fake concept, but is a type of air-core transformer.

It is possible to utilize energy stored in air using a wind turbine, check them out!

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wind_turbine

However some people say that they blow if constructed inaccurately.

Comment: It can be pretty efficient for an air-cored transformer. The concept is used in some commercial high voltage supplies, where the insulation requirement is met by coil separation, then the resonant effect is used to overcome the drawbacks of low coupling.

Comment: I didn't know it was used in the industry, thanks for enlightment!